# Extract numbers that start with 00 in .txt file

Tags: string, windows, batch-file

Hi I am trying to find a way to determine a constant in a string and then extract a set amount of characters to the left of that constant.

e.g -
I have a `.txt` file, somewhere in that file there are the numbers `00nnn` examples of the numbers would be `00234 00765 ....`

So I use

```
@echo off
findstr /i "00" *.txt > Listfile.txt
end
```

To find all the strings with the constant `00`

Now I have

```
        00013       Jonas   Jonas
2015-12-09 12:36:41     Bell (waterproof)   
-   Technical Account
        00014       Jonas           Bell    
-   Technical Account
        00019       Jonas   Jonas
2016-09-12 09:11:12             T16032611   Technical Account
        00055   -   Jonas   Jonas
2016-04-29 08:05:14             T16041312   Technical Account
        00057       Jonas   Jonas
2016-04-04 14:36:50             T15123112   Technical Account
        00067       Jonas   Jonas
2016-06-24 09:33:35             T15123112   Technical Account
    00570       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00571       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00572       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00573       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00574       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00575       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00576       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00577       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00578       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical
```

Next I tried :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (test.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 SET "digits=5!line:~-0,5!"
 FOR /L %%z IN (0,1,5) DO SET "digits=!digits:%%z=!"
 IF NOT DEFINED digits ECHO(!line:~0,5!
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

However my problem with this is that there are spaces in the strings and how would I extract the numbers when some start at `"digits=5!line:~-0,5!"` and others at `"digits=13!line:~-8,13!"` as an example.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there always spaces in front of the `00`?

Comment: Mmmm... Do you want to "count n characters to the left of `00`" or you want to "extract the numbers that start with `00`"? Your question is confusing...

Comment: Apologies, I would like to extract the numbers that start with 00 @Aacini

Comment: I suggest you to edit both the question title and description to be clearer (don't insert unrelated information). Also, you must include your own code even if it fails.

Comment: The reason why the file is messy is because I copy/pasted the details from a website. If I could find a way to find every `00nnn` number in the file I would not have to worry about what condition the file was in as long as I could get those numbers by extracting all the characters that fit the criteria `00nnn`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"
   for /F %%b in ("!line:*00=!") do echo 00%%b
)
```

The input data should have **one** `00nnn` number *per line*, so I reformatted your example data this way:

```
        00013       Jonas   Jonas
2015-12-09 12:36:41     Bell (waterproof)   -   Technical Account        00014       Jonas           Bell    
-   Technical Account        00019       Jonas   Jonas
2016-09-12 09:11:12             T16032611   Technical Account        00055   -   Jonas   Jonas
2016-04-29 08:05:14             T16041312   Technical Account        00057       Jonas   Jonas
2016-04-04 14:36:50             T15123112   Technical Account        00067       Jonas   Jonas
2016-06-24 09:33:35             T15123112   Technical Account    00570       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00571       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00572       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00573       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00574       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00575       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00576       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00577       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical Account
        00578       Jonas                   T16041312   Technical
```

Output example:

```
00013
00014
00019
00055
00057
00067
00570
00571
00572
00573
00574
00575
00576
00577
00578
```

**EDIT**: *New method added using JScript*

My first answer is a simple method to solve this problem using just a small Batch file. However, now that other answers had suggested to use *regular expressions* you should know that you don't need to mess with non-standard utilities (like grep) nor PowerShell in order to use a simple regex in a Batch file. You may use a couple lines of [JScript language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yek4tbz0(v=vs.84).aspx) that comes preinstalled on all Windows versions from XP on:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < test.txt
goto :EOF

@end

var match, search = /00\d{3}/g, file = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll();
while ( match = search.exec(file) ) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(match[0]);
```

Copy this code in a Batch file (.bat extension); this code run *much faster* than the PowerShell solution. You may also get the complete solution to your problem using the next line, that review all *.txt files and extract the numbers in one operation:

```
findstr /i "00" *.txt | cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
```

Comment: @RyanBemrose: Note that I did NOT wrote: _"mess with non-standard utilities (like grep or PowerShell)..."_. I think that _"mess with non-standard utilities nor PowerShell..."_ state that "non-standard utilities" and "PowerShell" are of different kind. However, I am not native English speaker, so please enlighten me if I am wrong...

Comment: @RyanBemrose: So? I am very interested in know if my English writting was wrong, in order to correct it in future posts (or if you just misinterpreted what I correctly wrote). Answer, please...

Comment: Your writing is fine.  I had misread "nor" as "or", and I had interpreted it as "non-standard utilities like (grep or powershell)".  I apologize and retract my comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex (from [Mark Setchell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39495066)) by invoking PowerShell and using the `Select-String` cmdlet to do the same thing as `grep`.

```
powershell -c "(sls '00\d{3}' YourFile).matches | select -exp value"
```

`Select-String` (`sls`) uses the regex `00\d{3}` to search for all lines containing the characters `00` followed by three digits and matches the whole number.  The `.matches` and `select` then extract only the part of the line that matches.

#### Output

```
00013
00014
00019
00055
00057
00067
00570
00571
00572
00573
00574
00575
00576
00577
00578
```

PowerShell is installed on every Windows PC; no need to install any third-party programs.

Comment: Nice answer - though I think Powershell only comes with Windows 8 and newer, but also needs an install on Windows XP and 7.

Comment: Vista and older require an install.  PS 2.0 comes with Win7.  Though they added a lot of language features between PS 2 and 3 and many scripts don't work on the older versions.

Answer (score 1):

extracting all numbers that start with `00` (assuming, there are only spaces or tabs before them):

```
 for /f %%a in ('type *.txt^|find "00"') do echo %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

Install **GNU grep** for **Windows** and run:

```
grep -Eo "00\d{3}" YourFile
```

to look for "00" followed by exactly 3 digits (`\d{3}`) and only (`-o`) print the part of the line that matches.

**Output**

```
00013
00014
00019
00055
00057
00067
00570
00571
00572
00573
00574
00575
00576
00577
00578
```